# parse query limit error

Tags: parse-platform, coronasdk

I am using the following code to limit the query to 1 object, however, I get error message "code 141 cannot call method "limit" of unexpected ....
I also tried  query.limit(1) but no luck.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getall", function(request, response) {
    query.limit = 1
    var query = new Parse.Query("english");
    query.find({
        success: function(results) {
            response.success(results);
        },
         error: function(error) {
             response.error("Error test");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Placing `query.limit = 1` after `var query = new Parse.Query("english");`

Comment: tried that before, that returns all objects.

Comment: Oops, it should be query.limit(1);

Comment: Did you try query.limit(1); which placing after `var query = new Parse.Query("english");`? And also note that, you could also use `query.first` without `query.limit` if you just want 1 result.

Comment: thanks guys this format query.limit(1) after var query ... works, can you put it in Answer so I can close it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing `query.limit(1);` after `var query = new Parse.Query("enbglish");` solved the problem.

And also `query.first` could achieve the purpose.

Comment: thanks for the response, would you know whether there is a way to get a random single(or more) query. I assume above code just gets the first entry based on the createdat field in parse.com.

Comment: Its sad that Parse do not provide a good manner to get a random one. But you could basically shuffle the query results by yourself and pick several from them.